Is examination of fern spores okay?
I want to be a pteridophytologist. In certain religions like Jainism, killing seeds or unicellular microorganisms is banned. Does sectioning of sporangia kill spores? Do the spores form a part of parent generation, or the offspring generation? Are they fully developed in the strobilus before dehiscence?

Welcome to HSE! This looks like a off topic question for this site as the question seeks purely scientific speculation.
